# Is it possible to add angular custom validation constraints conditionally?

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

The ng-required attribute is helpful to make a field required based on a condition:

`<input ... ng-required="object.isRequired" \>`

But how can this type of use be extended into using my own custom validation directives? For example, say I have a custom validation fieldsMatch. Now I want to add this validation to the input field based on the property "object.needsToMatch". I would hope there would be something like:

`<input ... fieldsMatch="object.needsToMatch"`

If the solution is to create another directive that would handle the condition, then how can I replace it inline (inside the input element)?

Secondary question: Then how to get this working when the custom validation takes an attribute, such as in the case of fieldsMatch validator, the model's field that this field needs to match with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a directive to handle this that is restricted to an attribute.

```
<input ... ng-model="inputModel" fieldMatchValidator fieldToMatch="object.needsToMatch" />
```

and in the directive:

```
...directive('field-match-validator', function(){

 require: 'ngModel',

 scope:{
  fieldToMatch: '='
 },

 link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
   //watch on the model and validate it against scope.fieldToMatch
 }
});
```

Obviously this is somewhat crude, but should get you started.

Comment: What I'm getting at is then how do I conditionally apply this constraint. Or would you suggest I have an argument that simply marks it as valid every time I validate (if object.needsToMatch === false)?

Comment: Well, one way is to simply not put it on fields that you don't want to validate it with. If you mean, you want it to be more dynamic - then yea I would have some checks in the link function to look at the state of the field to match (they should probably be there anyway).

Comment: I'm guessing that this is the best approach, I have yet to find another way. I'm marking it as the answer for now. Ideally I wouldn't need to enter the directive link function at all, but that seems to be asking a lot ;).